# Why does searching on Lucene NOT_ANALYZED literal fields return 0 results?

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

When I build my Lucene index (.NET), I add some identifier fields as NOT_ANALYZED - i.e. they will be stored "as is", i.e. Language is simply "EN" or "JP". If I understand, this is the correct way to store keys, as opposed to free text.

```
doc.Add(new NumericField("id", Field.Store.YES, true).SetIntValue(id));
doc.Add(new Field("language", language, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
doc.Add(new Field("headline", headline, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
```

Searches on the analysed field return results, i.e.

```
headline:oversight
```

Returns results, but simple queries on the NOT_ANALYZED fields do not:

```
language:EN
```

Or

```
id:120
id:[120 TO 120]
```

(I assume id, stored as a NumericField is inherently stored as NOT_ANALYZED)

I can see these values in the index via [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) - they are definitely being stored. Why are the queries not working against simple literal fields?

Thanks

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

NOT_ANALYZED means that the term dictionary will not contain any reference to that field, so no searches against it will yield results. If you want the field to be indexed as is I suggest you use a `KeywordAnalyzer` which will keep the text as given but index it and make it visible inside the term dictionary. Also , as a side note, the `Field.Index` enum is deprecated so I'd suggest you move away from that too